# Continous functions and convergence radius

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

I want to proof the following:

Let $(a_n)_n \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence and let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ be a series with convergence radius $1$.

Further, let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ be convergent.

Then
$$
f: (-1, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n
$$

is a continuous function.

I already know that $f_{\vert (-1, 1)}$ is continuous which might be useful, I think.

Comment: This is Abel's result, please have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem#Outline_of_proof

Comment: Essentially you are showing $\lim_{x \nearrow 1} f(x) = f(1)$ which is Abel's Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use wiestrass M test result to prove the convergence.

Comment: We don't know $\sum|a_n| < \infty,$ so how could Weierstrass M apply?